# Alternative text for keywords?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

`font-lock-add-keywords` lets users highlight keywords. Can you also specify an alternative text? For example, in C source code, besides using a special face, we may wish to visualize `!` as `not`, `&&` as `and`, etc.

Comment: You can do some such things using code like that in some of the stuff linked from [Pretty Symbol](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PrettySymbol).

Comment: `prettify-symbols-mode` comes close, but it can replace matches with just one character, it seems.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said some of the stuff. Unless someone has a simple solution you may need to create overlays with `display-property`, or some such.

Comment: @Elena, I think you can use Prettiy Symbol Mode to replace something into more than one character. The documentation says "CHARACTER can be a character, or it can be a list or vector, in which case it will be used to compose the new symbol as per the
third argument of `compose-region`." Well, `compose-region` accepts strings, so my guess is that you can use a string, if not something like `(?a ?n ?d)` might work. (If someone has more time than I do, feel tree to try this and post an answer.)

Comment: @Lindydancer I have tried with `(?a ?n ?d)`, but the replacement works by compressing the characters in the same box. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Drew Prettify Symbols Mode seems the only available solution. Please provide your suggestion as an answer, otherwise I will have to write an answer myself. Thanks.

Comment: @elena: Please write up an answer, incorporating Lindydancer's mention that the replacement need not be a single character. Thx. (And you can accept your own answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @Drew and @Lindydancer, Prettify Symbols Mode - available with vanilla Emacs - allows for sequences of characters to be displayed by a custom character sequence, by customizing the `prettify-symbols-alist` buffer-local variable. Examples:

```
(push '("&&" . "∧") prettify-symbols-alist) ; Single character replacement.

(push '("&&" . (?a ?n ?d)) prettify-symbols-alist) ; String replacement.
```